# What information is lost on a connection when passing it through a aws load balancer?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

Bit of a newbie question here. What happens when traffic is forwareded through a load balancer?  I had always assumed that load balancers just forwarded connections from clients to one of a set of servers, without much in the way of interpretation.

I have a application which requires a mysql connection to make a legacy library hppy. The DB is used only for short-term job tracking data - if the data is lost, meh.  It isn't the system of record.  The load is minimal.  Even the disk size is < 10G.  But if that connecton goes away, the legacy library gets very unhappy.

Corporate policies prevent me from using RDS, and I'm having a some trouble getting an HA cluster set up - especially since I'm not concerned with the usual data backup, replication, etc.

Our other servers are all deployed to AWS using Ec2- autoscaling groups.  For the most part, each server is a singleton, and we use the ASG to ensure one is mostly-up - the health checks are all on the order of 10 or 20 minutes.

I'd like to throw the mysql instance into an ASG also, but am having trouble passing traffic through the associated LB.  I gather from Google that you can't just stick a LB in front of a mysql instance,  but would expect that to be for data-quality issues.

I can use DNS to ignore around the LB entirely, so it isn't a hard blocker, and in a harder system, this would be the wrong answer anyway.  But I don't understand at a protocol level why the traffic doesn't go through.

Load Balancer Port Configuration:
3306 (TCP) forwarding to 3306 (TCP)

==========
Update.
Actually, the problem here seems to have been LB configuration.  After switching to an internal LB and restarting the clients, everything is humming along.

I did have to flush-hosts on the database as well, still puzzling through where the bad connectons came from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I did have to flush-hosts on the database as well, still puzzling through where the bad connectons came from.

You'll have to do that again, soon enough, unless you increase the value of [`max_connect_errors`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connect_errors) in the server configuration, because the **ELB health checks will be interpreted by MySQL as a bad connection**, since ELB connects and disconnects without authenticating.  Rack up enough of these and the inbound connections will again be denied.  In a secure environment, a host with significant connect errors doesn't really pose a significant threat to the server, so increasing `max_connect_errors`, significantly, to work around this should be fine.

You can `SET GLOBAL LOG_WARNINGS = 2;` on the MySQL Server and then check the MySQL error log (`SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'log_error';` to find the path to the error log).  This value (2) is actually a good default setting to use all the time for [`log_warnings`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_warnings).

Otherwise, yes, you can proxy TCP connections through ELB or any other TCP load balancer to MySQL, but the answer to "what you lose" is that you lose the identity of the host (IP address and port) that originated the connection, and MySQL will see the IP address of the ELB, instead... so if your authentication at the MySQL layer requires certain users to be coming in from specific IP addresses or ranges, then MySQL will not see that.  ELB supports the `PROXY` protocol, which makes that source IP and port information available again on TCP connections, but MySQL doesn't support the `PROXY` protocol, so that's out.

An alternative load balancer for MySQL is HAProxy, which understands enough of the MySQL protocol to actually try to log in to the server, and then disconnect again, when performing its health checks.  (I'm not affiliated with that product or project, but use it extensively.) Unlike ELB, it supports the concept of "backup" servers with don't go online unless the primary servers are down.  With that in mind, I was able to write a "dummy MySQL server" to use as a backup server of last resort, which simply returns an error that the MySQL client recognizes as a valid message from a MySQL server... so that when this is encountered, the application fails *quickly* and decisively (no long timeouts), with a message in the application log that points devops to the nature of the problem.  When no servers are available, I respond with a fake error (along with the message, the error code is configurable, but this one, if interpreted by a client library that translates error codes, means "server shutdown in progress"):

```
$ mysql --host x.x.x.x --port xxxxx
ERROR 1053 (HY000): No healthy MySQL servers are available to provide the requested service (but the connection to the load balancer was successful)
$ mysqldump --host x.x.x.x --port xxxx --all-databases 
mysqldump: Got error: 1053: No healthy MySQL servers are available to provide the requested service (but the connection to the load balancer was successful) when trying to connect
```

Neat, huh?

Comment: Interesting, and useful.  I think there area lot of things that would be better,this was more of a band-aid - for any system requiring any degree of reliability, RDS would be a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

It's not generally possible to "forward" a TCP connection. Load balancers terminate the connection from the client and open a new connection to the origin server, so any connection-specific information that the load balancer doesn't collect and pass on to the origin is lost -- most notably the source IP address (often passed to the origin server using the X-Forwarded-For header) and source port number.

Amazon Elastic Load Balancers also have a short timeout period, which generally prevents them from being used for persistent database connections where the client expects the connection to stay open and available. They've recently introduced the ability to customise the timeout, up to a maximum of 3600 seconds (one hour), which might be enough for you.

Comment: I will monitor into the timeouts. I /think/ the old libraries open a connection and write a hiccup once a minute, without anything smart like connection pooling.

Comment: Yup, they were sitting with their connections open for hours.